# Using .map() helper with bootstrap <Col sm="4" /> layout in React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm using also `ReduxLazyScroll` for infinite scroll effect and it worked but before it was just `ul -> li` list. Now I want my app to generate 3 cards one beside another in bootstrap-grid style, like so:

```
    <Row>
      <Col sm="4">.col-3</Col>
      <Col sm="4">.col-3</Col>
      <Col sm="4">.col-3</Col>
    </Row>
```

And I have some logic problem, which I can't wrap my head around.
So there is the code of parent component ( `BeerListingScroll` ) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import ReduxLazyScroll from 'redux-lazy-scroll';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchBeers } from '../../actions/';

import BeersListItem from '../../components/BeersListItem';
import ProgressIndicator from '../../components/ProgressIndicator';

class BeerListingScroll extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.loadBeers = this.loadBeers.bind(this);
  }

  loadBeers() {
    const { skip, limit } = this.props.beers;
    this.props.fetchBeers(skip, limit);
  }

  render() {
    const { beersArray, isFetching, errorMessage, hasMore } = this.props.beers;
    return (
      <Container>
        <ReduxLazyScroll
          isFetching={isFetching}
          errorMessage={errorMessage}
          loadMore={this.loadBeers}
          hasMore={hasMore}
        >
          {beersArray.map(beer => (
            <Row>
              <Col xs="12" sm="4">
                <BeersListItem key={beer.id} beer={beer} />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="12" sm="4">
                <BeersListItem key={beer.id} beer={beer} />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="12" sm="4">
                <BeersListItem key={beer.id} beer={beer} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          ))}
        </ReduxLazyScroll>
      </Container>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    beers: state.beers,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchBeers }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BeerListingScroll);
```

So I'm using beersArray.map helper and I know that that logic **doesn't make sense** inside `map`:

```
       <Row>
          <Col xs="12" sm="4">
            <BeersListItem key={beer.id} beer={beer} />
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" sm="4">
            <BeersListItem key={beer.id} beer={beer} />
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" sm="4">
            <BeersListItem key={beer.id} beer={beer} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
```

because I'm loading each `beer` element 3 times and then it looks like that -> 
img
[image]

---

The question is: **How should I refactor that code to get first, second and third array element in the first row, 4th, 5th, 6th in the second row etc?**

---

Desired outcome:

[image]

And here you have child component ( `BeerListItem` )

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardSubtitle,
  Button,
} from 'reactstrap';

const BeerListItem = ({ beer }) => (
  <div>
    <Card>
      <CardImg top width="100%" src={beer.image_url} alt="beer" />
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle>{beer.name}</CardTitle>
        <CardSubtitle>{beer.tagline}</CardSubtitle>
        <Button>More details</Button>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  </div>
);

export default BeerListItem;
```

And full project on github - > [Link to github](https://github.com/elminsterrr/beer-app-q)

Comment: Since Bootstrap uses `flex` display layout, I don't see the point of forcing 3 items in a row. Moreover, your items in map need a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this you could group them together in 3's in a nested array, so instead of `[beer1,beer2,beer3,beer4,...]` you have `[[beer1,beer2,beer3],[beer4,..,..],...]` then you can iterate them in groups, with a row per beer group and a column per beer in that group:

```
beerGroupsArray.map(beerGroup => (
    <Row>
        {
            beerGroup.map(beer => {
                <Col xs="12" sm="4">
                    <BeersListItem key={beer.id} beer={beer} />
                </Col>
            })
        }
    </Row>
))}
```

That's just one example of how to do it though, based on your data and use case there might be a cleaner, more robust method.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice beers array and then iterate through slices.

By that, you will have new Row for each slice (consist 3 different beer item)

```
const numberOfRows = ceil(beersArray.length / 3)

Array(numberOfRows).fill().map((_, rowIndex) => (
    <Row key={rowIndex}>
     {
       beersArray.slice(rowIndex * 3, (rowIndex *3) + 3).map(beer => (
        <Col xs="12" sm="4">
          <BeersListItem key={beer.id} beer={beer} />
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Row>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the optimized answer based on @muhammet-enginar 's answer!

```
{Array(parseInt(filteredFarms.length / 1))
.fill()
.map((_, colIndex) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-lg-3">
        {filteredFarms
          ?.slice(colIndex * 4, colIndex * 4 + 4)
          ?.map((filter, key) => {
            return (
              <>
                <li>{filter.farm}</li>
              </>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
});}
```

It contains return because it's reactjs/nextjs code, I also used parseInt because of the decimal which may cause issues if items are even.